# PUTTY ncurses A_BLINK have no effect

Tags: c++, linux, putty, ncurses

I try to run this sample code, `A_BOLD` seems working, but `A_BLINK`. I am sure the terminal can support blink effect, because I already click enable blinking text in `putty` settings, but it is still not working.

I am compiling with:

```
g++-8.2.0 -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fsanitize=address,undefined,pointer-compare,pointer-subtract -fstack-clash-protection -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -lncurses++ -lmenu -lpanel -lform -lutil -lncurses
```

Thanks for any help.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main(void){

    initscr();
    attron(A_BOLD);
    addstr("Twinkle, twinkle little star\n");
    attron(A_BLINK);
    addstr("How I wonder what you are.\n");
    refresh();
    getchar();
    endwin();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Some terminals don't implement blink.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151673/attrona-blink-using-ncurses-does-nothing)

Comment: See this answer on [Unix StackExchange: some terminals don't implement blink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151717/60995).

Comment: works for me with TERM=putty, TERM=xterm

Comment: @ThomasDickey what do you mean TERM = putty?

Comment: the *environment variable*, which PuTTY sets (incorrectly) to **`xterm`**.  Either way, the terminal description tells ncurses how to use blink, and either way, the sample program works (for me).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks very much. I am still little confuse, can you explain a little bit. When I type echo $TERM. It gives xterm-color. What next I need to do?

Comment: type **`export TERM=xterm`** ("putty" may not be installed, but "xterm" surely is).

Comment: @TedPercival Thanks I already read this.

Comment: you have probably to adjust your putty emulation in the configuration and also the correct value for the TERM environment variable in the host.